# My space bar delete text on Google search or youtube

Tags: google-search

When I hit space bar on Google search, my text is deleted. On Microsoft word, I don't have this problem. I don't think because of Ins button. Would anyone tell me how to fix that? Thank a lot!

Comment: Which OS, PC browser version etc.?

Comment: can you be specific about your problem? edit your question.. not understandable...!

Comment: I use a Mac. When I type a word on Google and hit spacebar to type the next word. The first word is deleted.